# What is $1 in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

What is the `$1`? Is that the match found for `(\d+)`?

```
$line =~ /^(\d+)\s/; 
next if(!defined($1) ) ;
$paperAnnot{$1} = $line;
```

Comment: Because it isn't mentioned elsewhere here yet, please see the perldoc perlre page for more information.

Comment: There is some more interesting information in `perldoc perlvar`. // Didn't notice it was already advised to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, `$1` means the first capturing group, in your example that is `(\d+)`

Answer (score 3):

Yep!  It's a group match.  Seeing the `next` there, it's probably in a loop.  However, a better way of handling what you have there would be to use a conditional and test the regex:

```
if ( $line =~ /^(\d+)\s/ ) {
    $paperAnnot{$1} = $line;
}
```

or even better, give $1 a name to make it self documenting:

```
if ( $line =~ /^(\d+)\s/ ) {
    my $index = $1;
    $paperAnnot{$index} = $line;
}
```

Also, you can find more about `$1`, and its brethren in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

And now in Perl 5.10 and newer, you can use named capture groups:

```
use 5.010; # or newer
...
if ( $line =~ /^(?<linenum>\d+)\s/ ) {
    $paperAnnot{ $+{linenum} } = $line;
}
```

See more on Named Capture Groups with [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, anything captured in parentheses is assigned to the $1, $2, $3... etc magic variables.  If the regexp doesn't match they'll be undefined.